# how to set random id when creating a record in strapi?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, back, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I have a problem, when I create manually in the strapi administration panel, in the id field it generates 1, but previously it generated a random id.
Should a configuration be done?
[image: 1]

Comment: I am using the version 3.3.2

Comment: Are you sure about it? I think ID is just an auto incremental integer.

Comment: in other versions it generated a key.

Comment: maybe the UID type is somewhat close to what you are looking for?